# php search request to Solr

Tags: php, search, solr

I'm a newbie and I am trying to make a web front end search UI that searches from an already implemented Solr indexes. Does anyone know a good tutorial on how to make a php search request using HTTP GET to Solr?

Comment: Google surely knows: https://www.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=php+solr+client&oq=PHP+SOLR&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l10.2710.8043.0.11424.14.10.3.1.1.0.299.2513.1j0j9.10.0...0.0...1c.1.12.hp.I1NdgaOhXgM

Comment: [RealTime Get](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/RealTime+Get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful: https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/
Or this
http://www.solarium-project.org/